# How to solve the problem of button flickering caused by css transition?

Tags: html, css

I have seen some solutions but they actually affect the design intended.
Is there any way to stop this flicker without altering the design?
I understand that the problem is that While hovering over a moving (or animated) element, it may just un-hover from the element because it moves beneath my cursor.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
 background-color: #FFEE32;
}
.button {
box-shadow: -10px 10px;
    background-color: #FFEE32;
    border: 3px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #202020;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px 30px;
      transition: all 0.15s linear 0s;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

.button:hover {
    top: 3px;
      transition: all 0.15s linear 0s;
    left: -3px;
    color: #FFEE32;
    background-color: #202020;
    border: #FFEE32;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 #ffe800 !important;
    position: relative;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Button - "Pressed Effect"</h2>
<div class="see">
<button class="button">Click Me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[check it out here, try to hover on edges from right and bottom](https://jsfiddle.net/xq6fsged/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an ::after pseudo element on your .button:hover, that will be slightly bigger than your actual button's area. As a result while you're hovering, the pseudo element will 'jump' under the cursor, that will prevent flickering - `.button` will not escape from your mouse :)

The below addition is not the perfect solution, but can be a working  solution for your problem

```css
.button:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:-10px;
  height: 130%;
  width: 110%;
  /*border: 3px solid blue;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Please note, by uncommenting the `border: 3px solid blue` rule you'll see the actual position and size of the pseudo element on hover.

Comment: your answer is the best aligned with the question but not very elegant. But because you are addressing the in accordance it was asked I'm accepting this one.

Answer (score 0):

because of border size & top,left position button is "flickering" when hover on corner side.

Add "3px" in border & remove "top & left" position.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
 background-color: #FFEE32;
}
.button {
box-shadow: -10px 10px;
    background-color: #FFEE32;
    border: 3px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #202020;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px 30px;
      transition: all 0.15s linear 0s;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

.button:hover {
    top: 0px;
      transition: all 0.15s linear 0s;
    left: 0px;
    color: #FFEE32;
    background-color: #202020;
    border:3px solid #FFEE32;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 #ffe800 !important;
    position: relative;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Button - "Pressed Effect"</h2>
<div class="see">
<button class="button">Click Me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer alters the original animation which was intended originally. But I am going with this.